# Converting Character data to QString in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qbytearray

[image]I'm working on a QT project (Qt Creator 5.2.1) with a function that receives a receives a device's IP address in a UDP datagram. I need to convert it to a QString to correctly output to the screen. The datagram is stored in a QByteArray called "buffer" as integer data - so the IP address of 10.1.10.60 shows up in the datagram as 0A010A3C. I'm trying to store the IP address in a QString "nburn_data". Currently I have this code for handling it:

```
nburn_data.append(QString::fromUtf8(buffer.left(2).toHex().toUpper(), 
    buffer.left(2).size()));
```

When the output is put to the screen (GUI) I don't get "10.1.10.60", I get "0A.01.0A.3C"

I've tried a few different methods to convert correctly, but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions?

Edit: @Laszlo Papp- I've attached an image along with the output (highlighted) from suggested code. [image: Relevant Code and Output]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots and instead copy paste the relevant text.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that screenshots were a forum rule violation. I'll remember that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what you try to do with your code as it seems to be out of order, but the following code works for me:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QByteArray buffer = "0A010A3C";
    QString nburn_data;
    bool ok;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i+=2) {
        if (i)
            nburn_data.append('.');
        nburn_data.append(QByteArray::number(buffer.mid(i, 2).toInt(&ok, 16)));
        // when using int buffer, then replace the above line with this:
        // nburn_data.append(buffer.mid(i, 2));
    }
    qDebug() << nburn_data;
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"10.1.10.60"
```

Edit: since you seem to have changed your input when updating the question, you will need to this update to my previous code answering your original question:

```
tempbuffer = tempbuffer.toHex(); // before the loop in your code
```

or you could just remove the needless number conversion in my loop, so replacing the inner line with this:

```
nburn_data.append(buffer.mid(i, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks @Laszlo, but maybe I did something wrong because that didn't work for me... I used "start" instead of nburn_data because the latter holds much more info than just the IP at this point in the code. Code:
`    bool ok;
    QByteArray tempbuff = buffer.left(4).data();

    qDebug() << "Temp: " << tempbuff.toHex();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i+=2)
    {
        if(i) start.append(".");
        start.append(QByteArray::number(tempbuff.mid(i, 2).toInt(&ok, 16)));
    }
    qDebug() << "IP Data: " << start;`

the output of the first qDebug() statment is "0a010a3c" and the second is "0.0.0.0"

Comment: I need a longer comment box....

The results have been the same for all my trials for some reason. I can view the data to be converted, it just won't convert for some reason.

Comment: yes I did try the code. I just attached a screenshot - the code is on the screen and the qDebug() output of that code section is highlighted in blue at the bottom.

Comment: the solution has been presented by hyde, and as mentioned to him, I'd have never thought to use the QStringLiteral macro... But thank you very much for your help in this manner. You have answered a few of my posts now, and as a bit of a newbie, it is very appreciated. I'm still uncertain why the other methods tried didn't work, honestly. All indications were that they should have. Thank you very much again for all your help!

Comment: @JediEngineer: it is because your tempbuffer does not actually contain the hexa number as you wrote in your question! Try to get the hex content before the loop into tempbuffer by converting itself, then it will all work. hyde's solution might work, but it is far from how Qt was designed and should be used IMHO. :) try `tempbuffer = tempbuffer.toHex();` before the loop, and then it will work. I personally suggest to use this style rather than low-level C'ish programming style in a C++ project, especially when you have convenience Qt methods for readability, etc. :)

Comment: @JediEngineer: also, my code is proof of concept. Do not forget to check against "ok" in production code whether it succeeded.

Comment: About using `toHex()` and `toInt(..,16)`: as far as I can see, there is no reason to mix in hex dump as text , that is totally needless complication. So I strongly disagree with *"suggest to use this style"* (of converting binary data to hex, then parsing that back to integers).

Comment: @hyde: as I already wrote, the OP's original question was unclear. He wrote that he had a hex input, in which case I think, my solution is the most Qt'ish. When he seems to have indicated that, he needs to have int input, it of course requires a bit of different solution. I do not see the problem with the .toHex(), personally. It seems logical to me, and eventually, it would be even better to send hex values through rather than integer. Other than that, I just used a loop to be less error-prone and more generic if someone needs to use this for something else. That is not a biggie though.

Comment: @LaszloPapp, I did try what you suggested, the output is still "0.0.0.0" - I took a screenshot and attached it to the original post for you to see in case of error. Sorry if I spelled your username wrong...

Comment: @JediEngineer: you are not using tempbuffer in the loop, but buffer. Change that to tempbuffer, so you fixed one, but introduced a new one. :)

Comment: @LaszloPapp Oops - I have overlooked that as I was re-typing. It works correctly, thank you!! I now have 2 ways of converting it! Yourself and hyde have resented me with two methods of accomplishing the same task. If you would be so kind, and for my own understanding, please enlighten me as to what makes one method preferable to the other?

Comment: @JediEngineer: great, does it also work with your original buffer (not hex) if you replace the line in the middle with this `nburn_data.append(buffer.mid(i, 2));`?

Comment: @LaszloPapp, thanks!hyde's solution made more sense to me at first because I'm used to C, not C++. But I need to be doing more with C++ ao I now have 2 ways of doing it, thanks to both of you.  :-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp - that's not what I said. I just said it made more sense to me AT FIRST. I also said I need to be doing more C++...

Comment: MY bad, that was the first working solution I tried. Changed now.

Comment: @hyde: he wrote `nburn_data.append(buffer.mid(i, 2));` would work, so I do not see the point for the longer formula which was written for the original question.

Comment: @hyde and LazsloPapp - this is what I ended up using - trying to stick to Qt methods as much as possible to better learn it: `        QString start;
        QByteArray tempbuff = buffer.left(4).toHex();
        bool ok;
        for (int i = 0; i< 8; i+=2){
            if (i)
                start.append(".");
            start.append(QByteArray::number(tempbuff.mid(i, 2).toInt(&ok, 16)));
        }`

Comment: @hyde: using C++/Qt methods is good Qt or C++. Low-level C casts are good C and non-C++Qt. I suggest **you** to put that up for codereview and see what answers you get, whether it is better to use the Qt/C++ .mid() method or your low-level C cast. You may get a head shot for using C-style cast in C++. ;) Also, please clean up the comment mess. I removed my comments a while ago, and there is a massive amount of obsolete comments hanging around.

Comment: Lazslo, seems we are talking about completely different things, there seems to be some misunderstanding... I can't believe you'd recommend processing binary data in a network packet by first converting it to hexdump text in C++ (or almost any language). But if you do recommend it, I'm not going to argue, I just suggest OP gets 3rd opinion about it.

Comment: @hyde: from my previous comment: `he wrote nburn_data.append(buffer.mid(i, 2)); would work, so I do not see the point for the longer formula which was written for the original question.` -> I think I made my position clear. :) AFAIK, Jedi wrote that he would use the longer formula because he wishes to learn Qt, which I think, means to use more methods than necessary to get familiar with more parts of Qt. I do not see the problem with that approach either for learning since it has no serious negative consequence here with few bytes.

Comment: It boils down to, whether this question is *"parsing and printing IPv4 address out of 8 characters of hexdump text"* or if it is *"printing IPv4 address out of 4 bytes of binary data"*. Your answer answers the first, my answer answers the 2nd. OP's actual problem is broader, and careful use of `QDataStream` might be the best approach for parsing a network packet in Qt, but that's kinda out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @hyde: I think you may have missed the answer update. I updated the answer a while ago to give idiomatic Qt solution for the updated question.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you anymore, and it has also worked for the OP... and even if it was so, it is easy to get that into int _without_ C cast. I am unsure what you are trying to debate or what you are trying to achieve. One thing is sure: this thread gets unfollowable for pretty much anyone else than us, full of obsolete comments, still... I am better stepping aside, I think.

Comment: Your update suggests `nburn_data.append(buffer.mid(i, 2));`. In that code, `mid` gives 2 bytes long `QByteArray`, which `QString::append` converts to Unicode either with `fromAscii` (Qt4) or `fromUtf8` (Qt5), before appending to `nburn_data`. I don't understand how that is useful in this question.

Comment: @hyde: There is a `toInt(&ok, 16)` to convert hex to int, and there is the second solution if you have ints. This is idiomatic Qt either way. I cannot see the problem, nor do I have any clue why you would argue for your C/C++ mixture code which is worse than clean C or C++. And fwiw, this is my last comment in this thread. I have lost all my motivation after being ignored. This whole argument is silly, especially for ugly C code.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, you want simply this:

```
nburn_data.append(QStringLiteral("%1.%2.%3.%4")
    .arg((unsigned)buffer[0]).arg((unsigned)buffer[1])
    .arg((unsigned)buffer[2]).arg((unsigned)buffer[3]));
```

For Qt4, replace `QStringLiteral` with `QString`. For certain kind of "C++ purity", replace C-style cast with `static_cast` (though I'd argue using C-style cast in case like this is better).

---

If you want to use features offered by Qt for parsing binary data, and IPv4 addresses in particular, then here's something for you study.

```
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QHostAddress> // note: .pro file needs QT += network
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main(void)
{
    // dummy data, big endian IPv4 address 10.1.10.60 at byte offset 4
    QByteArray buffer = QByteArray::fromHex("FFFFFFFF0A010A3CFFFFFFFF");
    int addr_offset = 4;

    // output string
    QString nburn_data("IP Address: ");

    Q_ASSERT(buffer.size() >= addr_offset + 4); // assert that buffer is big enough

    // initialize QDataStream for parsing buffer data
    QDataStream parser(&buffer, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    //parser.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian); // big endian is default
    parser.skipRawData(addr_offset);               // only needed if not at offset 0

    // parse the address
    quint32 addr = 0x00BADBAD;                    // 0.x.x.x is invalid IPv4 addr
    parser >> addr;                               // actual parsing happens here
    Q_ASSERT(parser.status() == QDataStream::Ok); // assert that buffer was big enough

    // use temporary QHostAddress object to convert address to string
    nburn_data.append(QHostAddress(addr).toString());

    qDebug() << nburn_data;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"IP Address: 10.1.10.60"
```

Notes:

- `QDataStream` has it's own serialization format for more complex and variable length data, so care must be taken when using it as general purpose binary data parser
- Since there is no other error checking than `Q_ASSERT` here, which will not do anything in release build, it's good to initialize `addr` instead of leaving it uninitialized, in case `QDataStream` has error and does not change its value.
- `QDataStream` can't recover from errors, so it should not be used directly on network socket, complete data should be put to `QByteArray` before parsing.
- while this code does not have a `QCoreApplication` instance, and none of the classes used here need it, many Qt classes do require it.

Comment: thank you. That produced the output I was looking for. my code now reads correctly. I would never have thought to use the QStringLiteral Macro - slipped my mind. Thank you very much!

Comment: @LaszloPapp, I apologize if my question was not well defined, I'm a hardware engineer thrust into software fairly recently with no experience and left to figure it out.. so to speak. So pardon if it is unclear. As I responded below, I have the data in int form that is as hyde mentioned, an IPv4 address. I need to convert it to text to display it on the screen. I've been able to get the output of "0A.01.0A.3C" but not "10.1.10.60" as previously mentioned, no matter what I did. I posted a screenshot of your most recent method to the original post.

Comment: @hyde - I'm not worried about optimization for this application. There's no critical timing involved, it's as simple as click a button and it sends a 16 byte packet to the unit, receives one back. That's it. Time between packets is 150 ms.

Comment: The gui has a "Host Port" box on it, the user types in a port number and clicks "Find Device" which broadcasts a 5 byte UDP packet to any devices on port 20034. The Netburner unit responds with a 148 byte packet. In that packet is the unit's IP address. If I understand your question correctly, then that packet from the netburner unit is the input. I am trying to extract the IP address from the packet, and convert it from int form to text to display on the screen. That's it.

Comment: Hodgepodge - 0A010A3C

Comment: @JediEngineer Oh, btw, just poking with note: I got inspired to actually test Qt features for getting IP out of binary data, check the edit. It's not really answering your original question any more I think, but I still added it to the answer, in case you find it interesting.

Comment: Thanks @hyde! This makes sense as well, and seems like another viable way for me to accomplish this task. I have other software I'm writing, I'm going to have to implement all these methods...